# joins across multiple SQLite database files

Tags: android, sqlite

Android has limitations on file system space for certain devices so my app errors once SQLite database file size grows beyond 5Mb and I run `VACUUM`. I plan to separate data across multiple SQLite files so I can simply delete the appropriate file when its data becomes obsolete. That way my main SQLite database never grows too big and I don't need to eat up space doing `VACUUM`.

How to make inner joins work across multiple SQLite files (when the primary data is in my main SQLite file and secondary data split across different SQLite files)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ATTACH DATABASE to query more than one database in your SQL:
http://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html

Answer (score 0):

Different databases means that they are different "things". You could query one db, them query the other db and join the two results in code (even if that includes join X on Y). But AFAIK, it's impossible to do that using sql only.