# Joint select from sqlite inmemory table and physical database tables

Tags: t-sql, sqlite, join

I was wondering if it is possible to, using SQLITE, do a joint SELECT from in-memory-tables and database tables?

Comment: You want to join tables from different databases?

Comment: same question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495204/joins-across-multiple-sqlite-db-files

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with "in-memory-tables" ?

Did you try with:

```
SELECT fields FROM table as alias, (SELECT fields FROM table) as alias2 WHERE alias.field = alias2.field
```

Or the same but use join